# How to insert entity into Azure Table Storage using Logic App Standard?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-logic-app-standard

Goal: read a blob from Azure Storage Container and insert some values into Azure Table Storage.

Using Logic App Consumption I could achieve this - after a few hiccups due to my first working with this service - and I slept well that night, thinking that with a Logic App Standard there should be a similar approach. I need to use the latte, being an enterprise application.

However, to my dismay the operation 'Insert or Replace Entity' or something else similar, that inserts an entity, does not exist in Logic App Standard for Azure Table Storage.
Am I missing out on anything? What should I do to be able to insert an entity, that initially looked something very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try navigating to your **Logic App >> your design >> Azure** instead of built-in from there you can able to find all the connectors similar to Consumption Logic app.

[image]

Comment: that was it, thank you, so silly of me